# super().__init__(self,name,age,gender,address) TypeError: __init__() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given

Tags: python, constructor, typeerror, superclass, positional-argument

when creating Student() instance, it shows type error, **super().**init**(self,name,age,gender,address) TypeError: **init**() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given**
I tried many way but i did not succeed. please help me to solve this!!!

````
    def __init__(self, house_name,street,dist,state,pin,country='India'):
        self.house_name = house_name
        self.street = street
        self.dist = dist
        self.state = state
        self.pin = pin
        self.country = country


class Person:
    CURR_ID = 0
    def __init__(self,name,age,gender,address):
        self.id = None
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
        self.address = []
        self.add_address(address)
        self.set_id()

    def add_address(self,address):
        if not isinstance(address, Address):
            raise ValueError('Invalid address...')
        elif isinstance(address,list):
            for entry in address:
                if not isinstance(address, Address):
                    raise ValueError('Invalid address...')
                self.address.append(entry)
        self.address = address
        return True

    def set_id(self):
        self.id = Person.CURR_ID + 1
        Person.CURR_ID += 1

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id


class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self,name,age,gender,address):
        super().__init__(self,name,age,gender,address)
        self.max_enroll = False
        self.course_enrolled = []




if __name__ == '__main__':
    s1 = Student('Student', 24,'M',Address('HouseName','Street','Dist','State', '112233'))
    print(s1.__dict__)```
````

Comment: You don't need to pass `self` explicitly when using `super()`. There's probably an appropriate duplicate, but the call would just be `super().__init__(name, age, gender, address)`.

Comment: Thank you... it solved.. but yesterday i tried this many time but nothing happend. @chepner